# Android client-server communcation format

Tags: android, json, rest, post, bson

I'm building an Android client for a web service that accepts POST data. We're standing on the fence which format to choose for the POST data. According to me, the easiest way is to send it in UrlEncoded format but server side developer thinks JSON is better.

What are the pros and cons of using UrlEncoded / jsonEncoded / bsonEncoded format?
I would avoid xmlencoded data, but what about the others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question greatly depends on what kind of data you're going to send. If your data is mostly string values, numbers and the like, probably JSON would be your best solution.

Avoid url-encoded data, use MultiPart instead -- it takes a bit more work, but it's more secure (url-encoded data it's visible in the server logs) and you may send large files (images?) easily.

Answer (score 2):

If you are sending maps (set of key-value pairs) and arrays, JSON is probably the easiest to work with from a developer standpoint on both client and server. If you need to optimize instead on use bandwidth usage for large set of non-media data, protobuf works well.